# Plot distribution of follow-up times according to event status

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I want to create a plot of the distribution of follow-up times of variable `futime` on x-axis according to event status in variable `fustat` on y-axis.

```
data(cancer, package="survival")
```

My attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ovarian, aes(x = futime, fill = factor(fustat))) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 50) +
  labs(x = "Futime", y = "Count", fill = "Fustat") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("0" = "red", "1" = "blue")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

But how to get it more nicely like [this](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial_files/figure-html/fuptimes-1.png)

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to specify alpha values for your fill - this makes the fill colours transparent so they can be visible when overlaid in the manner seen in your example.

Comment: Like geom_histogram(binwidth = 50, alpha = 0.5)

Comment: and you will need `position = "identity"` as well for the overlapping to work. - see example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with a built-in dataset as we don't have your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = factor(Species))) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, alpha = 0.4, position = "identity")
```

gives:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. How to get rid of the grey space at the bottom and left?

Comment: Play with your theme settings - `theme_minimal()` is a good start point.